# Appending file name giving back incorrect string

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to add a `DateTime` stamp, a prefix and a unique number to a file name. My desired output is:

> \ParentDirectory\Sub Directory\Another Sub Directory\Prefix- Unique Number - 11 29 2016 2 07 30 PM.xlsx

`Prefix` and `Unique Number` above will be passed into the function. I'm using the following method to achieve this:

```
public static string AppendDateTimeToFileName(this string fileName, string prefix, string uniqueNumber)
{
    return string.Concat(
        Path.GetFullPath(fileName),
        Path.Combine(prefix + " - " + uniqueNumber + " - "),
        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName),
        DateTime.Now.ToString()
        .Replace("/", " ")
        .Replace(":", " ")
        .Trim(),
        Path.GetExtension(fileName)
        );
}
```

I call the above method as:

```
string fileName = @"\\ParentDirectory\Sub Directory\Another Sub Directory\MyFile.xlsx";
string adjustedFileName = fileName.AppendDateTimeToFileName("Shipping Note", "0254900");
```

The output I receive is as follows:

> \ParentDirectory\Sub Directory\Another Sub Directory\Shipping Note -\0254900 - 11 29 2016 2 08 10 PM

As you can see in the above output the string is incorrect, firstly I get an extra `-\` and the file extension isn't coming through either. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please.

Comment: Path.GetFullPath(fileName) returns the full path not the filename.

Comment: @AnthonyLambert oh ok, but how comes I get an extra `-\` in my returned value? Also I want to return the full path along with the appended file because later on I save the file to the path with the new name

Comment: You don't need `Path.Combine` just to concatenate the prefix and number together.  `Path.Combine` is for combining parts of a path with the appropriate path separator.

Comment: Your method has an argument called `uniqueNumber`, but you use something called `rmaNumber` instead.  When I fix that my result is "\\ParentDirectory\Sub Directory\Another Sub Directory\MyFile.xlsxShipping Note - 0254900 - MyFile11 29 2016 9 38 04 AM.xlsx"

Comment: @juharr Sorry that was a typo from when I was trying out a different param.

Comment: Path.Combine(prefix + " *-* " + rmaNumber + " - "), I think because you have the `-` there? You ` \ ` : Here is your answer: It is not realy a \ which is added but a null character

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292850/c-sharp-what-does-0-equate-to

Comment: @juharr How come `MyFile.xlsx` isn't being appended? It'll work if it's just the file name but I need to return the entire directory path with it too

Comment: You really should be able to pin the problem down to the individual part(s) that go into the `string.Concat` yourself...

Comment: @Code Not sure why you got a result that was different, but as Anthony said `GetFullPath` will include the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted version of your code give the following output:

> \ParentDirectory\Sub Directory\Another Sub Directory\MyFile.xlsxShipping Note - 0254900 - MyFile29 11 2016 15 46 48.xlsx

and NOT as you posted:

> \ParentDirectory\Sub Directory\Another Sub Directory\Shipping Note -\0254900 - 11 29 2016 2 08 10 PM

if your desired output is:

> \ParentDirectory\Sub Directory\Another Sub Directory\Prefix- Unique Number - 11 29 2016 2 07 30 PM.xlsx

You need to move the directory into the `Path.Combine` and use `GetDirectoryName`. Also remove the line:

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
```

since in your desired output I don't see the old file name `"MyFile"`.
This code:

```
public static string AppendDateTimeToFileName(this string fileName, string prefix, string uniqueNumber)
{
    return string.Concat(               
        Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), prefix + " - " + uniqueNumber + " - "),
        DateTime.Now.ToString()
        .Replace(".", " ")
        .Replace(":", " ")
        .Trim(),
        Path.GetExtension(fileName)
        );
}
```

will yield the following output:

> \ParentDirectory\Sub Directory\Another Sub Directory\Shipping Note - 0254900 - 29 11 2016 15 39 37.xlsx

Comment: I've just tried this and it works perfectly! Thank you. just a quick note I updated this line `.Replace(".", " ")` to `.Replace("/", " ")`

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it

```
public static string AppendDateTimeToFileName(this string fileName, string prefix, string uniqueNumber)
{
    return Path.Combine(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName),
        string.Concat(
            prefix,
            " - ",
            uniqueNumber,
            " - ",
            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName),
            DateTime.Now.ToString("MM dd yyyy h mm ss tt"),
            Path.GetExtension(fileName)));
}
```

This correctly uses `Path.Combine` to combine the directory from `Path.GetDirectoryName` and you're new concatenated file name.  Note I also used a date format string instead of the replacements.  You might want to consider changing that format and putting a separator between the file name and the date.